# how to add the quantity to existing product in redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm writing add to cart function it working perfectly the problem is when I want to add the quantity to existing product based on the id. I'm using redux-sauce to handle the reducer. How to handle the quantity of an existing product.

```
let exist = state.products.find(v=> v.id === item.id )
```

```
export const addToCart = (state, { item }) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    products: [...state.products, { ...item, qty: 1 }],
  };
};
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to create another action, so you can

```
const addItemsToCart = (state, { items }) => ({
  ...state,
  products: [...state.products, ...items],
});
```

Otherwise, you'd need to refactor your previous action and the places from where you're calling it